# having a problem knitting my r markdown document

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, symbols

Im trying to draw data from yahoo using `getsymbols`
im using r markdown

I´ve tried running all components separately and it work but one i tried to knit the document the i get errors

```
wEnd<- Sys.Date()
wstart<- Sys.Date()-365

getSymbols("ETH-USD", src = "yahoo",from=wstart,to= wEnd )
getSymbols("BTC-USD", src = "yahoo",from=wstart,to= wEnd )
getSymbols("XRP-USD", src = "yahoo",from=wstart,to= wEnd )

ETH_USD <- `ETH-USD`
BTC_USD <- `BTC-USD`
XRP_USD <- `XRP-USD`
```

````
### chart 1 {}
```
{r cars}
library(xts)

dygraph(BTC_USD)
dyCandlestick()
```
````

for some reason the dygraphs cannot read the data in so it gives me errors

expected outcome would be for the file to be knitted together and run

Comment: I think you forgot the `%>% ` after `dygraph(BTC_USD)`. Is this possible? When I insert them, everything knits fine.

Comment: ### prediction
```{r prdiction}

btcopen <- BTC_USD$`BTC-USD.Open`
btcpre <- auto.arima(btcopen)
plot(forecast(btcpre,7))
``` thanks for the input that knited but im also tring to us auto.arima and this will not knit any ideas ?